# Aligning two databases using textual analysis/text mining in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

**Task:** My task is to move textual information from one database to another database using textual analysis, text mining, or machine learning in R.

So far, I have created an excel database using common fields/areas, but I don't know what to do next after that. If anyone has an idea of what I could do next, I am all ears.

Thank you all!

Comment: To create R dataframes from excel workbooks, you can try the read_xlsx() function from the readxl package.

Comment: Please take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).